# Sharing data from asynchronous calls amongst directives in AngularJS with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, typescript, angular-promise

I can find bits and pieces of how to solve this, but no concrete way to make it work.

I have an asynchronous call to a server to fetch data in AngularJS and wish to store it in a variable. This variable then needs to be accessible to all the directives in the app, but they obviously all need to wait for the variable to be assigned before they can use it. I'm also using TypeScript and its `export` functionality to spin directives from their own functions.

## Controller

```
export class MainController{
   fundData: Object;

   constructor(scope, FundService) {

       FundService.fetchData('some_param').then(d => {
           let data = d[0],
               fundProps = data.properties_pub;

           this.fundData = {
               'isin': data.clientCode,
               'nav': fundProps.nav.value,
               'nav_change': fundProps.nav_change.value.toFixed(2),
               'nav_change_direction': change,
               'total_aum': fundProps.net_asset.value.toFixed(2)
           };

           scope.ctrl = this;
       });  
   }
}
```

## Directive

```
class OverviewController {
    scope: ng.IScope;

    constructor(scope){

        scope.$watch('data', newVal => {
            console.log(newVal);
        });
    }
}

OverviewController.$inject = ['$scope'];

export function overview(): ng.IDirective {
    return {        
        restrict : "C",
        controller : OverviewController,
        controllerAs : "overview",
        template : require("../templates/overview"),
        bindToController :{
            data: '='
        }
    }
}
```

## HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="overview" data="ctrl.fundData"></div>
</div>
```

## Bootstrap Process

```
let module = angular.module(MODULE_NAME,[])
                .controller('MainController', ['$scope','FundService', MainController])
                .service('FundService', FundService)
                .directive('overview', overview);
```

## Things I've Tried:

### $rootScope

I can set something static and share it, so this works:

```
$rootScope.data = 2;
```

This doesn't:

```
someFunction().then(data => { $rootScope.data = data });
```

Maybe there's something about promises in $rootScope I don't understand.

### Setting in controller

I can set the result of the call to a variable in the controller, set that to an attribute in the directive, and then bind the attribute to its controller, but this doesn't work either, even if I use `$watch` on the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is fetch the data, store it in a service (which I think you are already doing) and then broadcast an event when the data in the service is updated. Here's an example (in raw javascript)

```
module.service('DataService', function(rootScope) {
    ...
    var data;
    services.setData = function(newData) {
        data = newData;
        rootScope.$broadcast('DataUpdated');
    };
    ...
});
```

And then in your directives all you would need to do is listen for the `'DataUpdated'` event:

```
scope.$on('DataUpdated', ...);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @PankajParkar using `rootScope` here to ensure the broadcasted event is received by the intended child scopes

Comment: @Robin how would I access the `newData` then? (sorry my knowledge of Angular isn't great)

Comment: @Robin EDIT: I assigned `newData` to `$rootScope`, which works! Don't know if this is a good practice though? Regardless, thanks a bunch

Comment: @Robin  my point is why don't shareable service directly take and set data, instead of having it event based

Comment: @PankajParkar it needs to be event based because of the asynchronous call. The service can't make a call for each directive due to performance